# Type mismatch user form

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a error mesage when I run this code.

```
Dim usf as object
If usfOKNAR01.Visible = True Then
    k = 1
    Set usf = VBA.UserForms(usfOKNAR01) 'here I'm getting the error
ElseIf usfOKNAR02.Visible = True Then
    k = 2
    Set usf = VBA.UserForms(usfOKNAR02) 'here I'm getting the error mesage
End If
```

I want to create a dynamic object control which is reffering to 2 Userforms called usfOKNAR01 and usfOKNAR02.

Depending which is visible the proper will be set and then used like this usf.Controls("txt" & k & "oknar13").Value in other part of my code.

I don't know where the issue can be?
Thank you for your help!

---

I have removed a part of my code and it seems to work but I don't know if this is the proper way to solve my issue.
Here the new code:

```
Dim usf as object 
If usfOKNAR01.Visible = True Then 
k = 1 Set 
usf = usfOKNAR01 
ElseIf usfOKNAR02.Visible = True Then 
k = 2 Set 
usf = usfOKNAR02 
End If
```

Comment: Hi, I want to create a dynamic object control which will be like this: usf.Controls("txt" & k & "oknar13").Value

Comment: Where is this code being run from?

Comment: I have removed a part of the code and it seems to work like I wanted. Here the code:Dim usf as object
If usfOKNAR01.Visible = True Then
    k = 1
    Set usf = usfOKNAR01
ElseIf usfOKNAR02.Visible = True Then
    k = 2
    Set usf = usfOKNAR02
End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the name or the class name as an index to `VBA.UserForms` - it only accepts Integer index arguments.  If you don't know the integer index of the collection, you'll have to iterate over it:

```
Dim usf As Object
Dim found As Boolean
If usfOKNAR01.Visible = True Then
    k = 1
    Dim candidate As Object
    For Each candidate In VBA.UserForms
        If TypeOf candidate Is usfOKNAR01 Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next usf
    If found Then Set usf = candidate
    '...
```

Since you need to do this at least twice, I'd recommend extracting it to a function.

Note that if either of the forms is not loaded when your code runs, VBA will instantiate them when you test whether they are Visible.